# PayPal IPN Simulator won't send IPN under strange conditions

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

So, I've been testing out my IPN script and developing it for what I need, but I've run into a problem in which I recieve the "**We're sorry, we could not send an IPN.**" error.

> All options not mentioned are the defaults

**Scenario 1 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
All default information.
```

**Scenario 2 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
Receiver_email: Example@domain.com
```

**Scenario 3 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
Receiver_email: Example@domain.com
Item_name: My Item
```

**Scenario 3 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
Receiver_email: Example@domain.com
Item_name: My Item
mc_gross: 39.99
```

**Scenario 4 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
All defaults;
custom: Jimmy|0
```

**Scenario 5 - Success**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
All defaults;
Reveiver_email: Example@domain.com
custom: Jimmy|0
```

**Scenario 6 - FAILED**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
All defaults;
Reveiver_email: Example@domain.com
Item_name: My Item
custom: Jimmy|0
```

**Scenario 7 - FAILED**

```
Transaction Type: Web Accept
Receiver_email: Example@domain.com
Item_name: My Item
mc_gross: 39.99
custom: Jimmy|0
```

So, why is it that I can send

> custom: Jimmy|0

in **scenario 4-5** and then send all of the other information as displayed in **scenario 1-3** without problems, but as soon as I add the value from **scenario 6** (the custom field) to my values to send, it breaks.

I've tested this with about 4-5 different values, and sent a total of almost IPN Requests trying to figure it out.

It seems that when using the Item_name and Custom methods together it causes this, as shown in **scenario 5 and 6**

**Note, when removing the seperator value from custom '|' the IPN will send, but why is the seperator causing problems when it worked in all of the other scenarios? I also extended the Custom field to numerous characters to make sure it wasn't a length issue.**

!! It seems that when changing the seperator being sent to the IPN it works fine, however it seems that the problem causing the error is actually my explode() method.

```
$custom = explode('~', $_POST['custom']);

$referral = $custom[0];
$software_type = $custom[1];
```

Whatever character I'm exploding from will cause the error.

However, while printing the $referral and $software_type to the error_log, it gives the correct values:

```
[04-Nov-2014 02:18:11 America/Los_Angeles] [Referral]: Jimmy
[04-Nov-2014 02:18:11 America/Los_Angeles] [Software]: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have something wrong in your IPN script causing it to fail when certain data gets included with it.  This would result in a value other than 200 OK getting sent back to PayPal's server, so they would assume it failed.

You should be able to check your web server logs to see the actual error(s) that are happening, which you would typically see in a browser if you were running it directly.

On that note, a good way to troubleshoot this sort of thing is to build your own simulator so you can do exactly that.  Build a basic HTML form with the action set to your IPN URL.  Include hidden fields that resemble the names/values of parameters you expect to get from the PayPal IPN.  Then load it in a browser and submit it directly so you can see the result on screen.

Keep in mind that when testing this way the data is not coming from PayPal's server.  As such, it will be UNVERIFIED, so if you have logic in your code to handle that you'll need to adjust it accordingly for testing this way.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, because explaining how to debug locally without using the paypal sandbox has helped me tremendously. I was able to find out where the script was breaking and why, as-well as cut down my development time by probably hours. Thanks again.